# On the prediction for raster files using glmms

Tags: raster, lme4, mixed-models, r-raster

I'm doing maps predictions using GLMM package `lme4` by using raster files through the function :

```
 Predictions<- predict(Full_stack_std, GLMM_,  type='response', re.form=NA)
```

Actually, when I count the number of the non-NA pixels in the predictors I find (2139692 and 2139184) but the number of the non-NA pixels for the probabilities  `Predictions` is 2139079.  The following code explains that maybe for the prediction we take only the pixels that are not NA for all the predictors :

```
library(raster)
library(terra)
library(purrr)
library(lme4)
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r1 <- raster(f)
r2 <- calc(r1, fun=function(x){ x[x < 500] <- NA; return(x)} )
r1 <- calc(r1, fun=function(x){ x[x > 1200] <- NA; return(x)} )
raste <-  rast(r1)
rNA <- terra:: global(!(is.na(raste)), sum, na.rm=TRUE)
print(paste0("Non-NA of r1", rNA))
raste <-  rast(r2)
rNA <- terra:: global(!(is.na(raste)), sum, na.rm=TRUE)
print(paste0("Non-NA of r2", rNA))


Y_ <- purrr:: rbernoulli(150, p = 0.4)
Y <- ifelse(Y_=='TRUE', 1, 0)
#Genrates the years for the random intercept
years <-  as.character(rdunif(150,b=5,a=1))
r1_ <- rnorm(150, 800, sd=50)
r2_ <- rnorm(150, 1000, sd=50)
my_data <- as.data.frame(cbind(Y, r1_, r2_, years))
colnames(my_data) <- c("Y", "r1", "r2", "years")
my_data$r1 <- as.numeric(as.character(my_data$r1))
my_data$r2 <- as.numeric(as.character(my_data$r2))
my_preds_Logit <- c("r1", "r2")
MODEL_FORM_GLM_Model <-    paste0('Y ~', paste(my_preds_Logit,collapse = "+"), paste0('+ (1 | years)'), collapse = "+")
GLMM_MODEL_Model_ <- glmer(as.formula(MODEL_FORM_GLM_Model) , 
                          data = my_data, family=binomial(link="logit"),
                          control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",
                                               optCtrl=list(maxfun=150000)))
r <- raster::stack(r1,r2)
names(r) <- c('r1', 'r2')
projection <- predict(r,GLMM_MODEL_Model_,   type='response', re.form=NA)
raste <-  rast(projection)
rNA <- terra:: global(!(is.na(raste)), sum, na.rm=TRUE)
print(paste0("Non-NA of r2", rNA))
```

Is there a way to measure the number of non-NA in raster1 and in raster2 to validate this?

Comment: Can you make a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example*. For example based on the example in `?raster::predict` ?

Comment: @RobertHijmans I edited my post and added a reproducible example.

Comment: Your example does not run: `Error in mkRespMod(fr, family = family) : 
  response must be numeric or factor`